# Local variable is modified unintentially

Tags: c++, c

When I pass (a,b) = (0,100) to this function, the variable `sum` is modified to 0 as if by magic. Im using Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0. and C++20.
I wonder why and how?

```
int need_match(int a, int b){
    int sum = 4;
    char buf[3];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    sprintf(buf, "%d", a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if(buf[i]-'0' >= 0){
            sum += match_map[buf[i]-'0'];
        }
    }
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    sprintf(buf, "%d", b);  // *** variable sum changes after this line ***
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if(buf[i]-'0' >= 0){
            sum += match_map[buf[i]-'0'];
        }
    }
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    sprintf(buf, "%d", a+b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if(buf[i]-'0' >= 0){
            sum += match_map[buf[i]-'0'];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `char buf[3];` can only hold up to 2 characters and the 0-terminator. So when you write `"100"` to it, it will write the 0-terminator out of bounds.

Comment: @mch in principle the null terminator isnt needed here, but yes `sprintf` adds it

Comment: @JoopEggen Im Sorry that is not what supposed to be, that might be a mistake. Ive just corrected it

Comment: What language is that. Seems to be C and not C++? Is the tag correct?

Comment: @mch So do you mean that `sum` is placed right after where `buf` is at in function stack? That surely makes sense

Comment: @ArminMontigny Im using a C++ compiler when writing this code and both is correct.

Comment: Then it is Caleths answer: for 100% the byte 0 is written outside `buf`, over say the four bytes of `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

> the variable sum is modified to 0 as if by magic.

Your program has undefined behaviour, so variables magically changing is allowed.

`sprintf` requires that buf be at least as long as the string written, including the 0 terminator. When you pass `100`, you need at least **4** characters in `buf`.